# ElasticSearch HasChild Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In my ElasticSearch instance, I have two types in a single index. Think of them as "Profile" and "ProfileMetadata". There may be many ProfileMetadata items pointing to a single Profile.

Profile contains basic user info. Say firstname. ProfileMetadata contains metadata for the user, say "Tags".

What I want to be able to do, is run a single query that may look like the following. "Firstname NOT tag". The user would type this into the search bar. It would be a single search bar to search across both types at once.

The two queries are below :

Profile Query

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "PersonalDetail.FirstName", 
            "PersonalDetail.LastName", 
            "PersonalDetail.Email"
          ], 
          "query": "John Smith NOT tag"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ProfileMetadata Query

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "has_child": 
        {
          "type": "ProfileMetadata", 
          "query": 
          {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "Tags"
              ], 
              "query": "John Smith NOT Tag"
            }

          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to combine these queries, so that we get all John Smiths without that particular tag. I am using NEST in C#, and at the moment I am taking both of these queries (In NEST form), and using an OR between them, which isn't working as I need it to. So I'm trying to break it down into pure ES form first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use only the second query, it will return all the matching parent document and then pass a filter on it representing your first query.

In this way you would not have to do a OR between two queries and might gain in performance with only one query+ filter.